# Ошибка в компиляторе

Tags: python, telebot

```
import asyncio
import time as time_d
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

import gspread as gspread
import requests
import telegram
from gspread.utils import rowcol_to_a1
import pandas as pd

import logging

#from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict({
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "bot-telegram-330607",
    "private_key_id": "770cc996d7c2169556a7efe505212ab7a1f99b50",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCe4yySgdRfOmax\noeZkppnPEvlyHcp/VDQtVQgPXBnCFQwibkOcGhFRGD6r28+fhg+fnoOsOtsr89ge\nu0W0VUHZJDIriZysHxM55QiweOsGoKJ8OCxna2OabGvLrfk1TlIpHfrO8tFVQe+l\nkL93+oSBZbnLbTS1YZsCjDYrALPZAIm0dYQ2yvK3XQz7s2qjJ3qxhR9LND3Gf1gs\n3w+aulDnHNikADHt4KEvWdvXWAV+4RZ1LvxbzHZyx7Ym4m+dVqVyomk0WYbFIXI+\nev3WOA1cXfMivBtpaeLQKVRUXPVG/AbH0O3YCiRiUCrXJfPZxsL8OtD5QEvUfMiM\niMqck5ZlAgMBAAECggEASPPPxFkeNLcw7cCDc5VXK8/vfqkVEA+OgX34XG0SWp2l\nW627F1KUvuJd7DTaCMnaJJT4qjy/41dr1PhxkdJPkK7g5kKiEBmYj02NBtIOP5XD\n5Ts5kCarrfy4JeX0dbhHWx+ryBePbBEBQsjKUQFSk8MsYq36tIljTfEo8ee5rBms\ns04cRazWgQ0G5lL2V68CemaMkGe8sPBkIWkjS35JSH51kmMgxWJ4i12qY68q0l5L\nCjZYOD+pp9Ub7vYqzoLE6jck+yDGEd75wFGQxyFBhFcZIC1Y03/rMdDhtTg+DQXy\nukJtQOPQGfVF4rRSW477g9Q7JXAyO52eXc/yORtCpQKBgQDTzyhthSVl4Tf+D9xr\nF1i2vJ21GXA3IfG9rDsE9LCuUShzkgfL5Lbyn3kUwymaI0PjSlK+ZcbxXwtTLiDj\nlLqORsS9eqgP3mr5X2pQAMfE5yzPgnFI687AklM9feIlDHj0hcpzS35KVPuhJN8L\noJM4qd36wFqRU6gi0ix2o2jCVwKBgQDACW8oCLqSGoYUG5xb0l/nCcf9AlnIeyV0\nK1ViLVp5vActyiKjGTS5qm2hXtjfM0dl4o9hoMbyogAxjzPJvdCuMEfitzg41VTe\nVo8mr43mlzMmx7Qg3QDIx1WUHDu+qrE34F24Ep/WBX3aDNiqgsewlOkieDLv6BZ4\nYz/aX/FPowKBgHSTIacVjv3BtTWJuUDfup3otcwE0jQl5I0GC/2wRsXKOT9SciQQ\nH3jtuJBq0azaF/Uy5NOR5KrYKr1/N+7J3tuLq6C1r2X8flf94d9ibpC6w3j6TCtc\nTZDDeDjx3dOSR8gdEs3eEQYMO+n3ByO5Hw4iv9/Qmog9yN5RWtN5IKFFAoGAKAzP\npeXMI1RsyhzIC05gueqMTvQCjZFBSm0PLZ6P0/um86HIf4NuP5qPqqwBRuuG5HTP\numixlUC8EZnwDw8LSoi/NUVI8HFtdcFPsZ3DVmgKPvg/VOtCkp0f9/e7bhRjSWf9\no7oeo6AZkzRCq60CwI0N4iZ3WRlqNklcs8p2pUkCgYEAgE5TToFzHK7vWA5qTycE\nVP7Z1asnG/5w0fNRRFipOETMpPK2p3149Un7r4vERR0XcW6ysRF5ZBVlYXDDbGAP\nuKJemSPH9TCr1y+KQb5V/852IL6JNyqOcyUsZLsztdupttTApqc4npA4oOpHS8IB\nU4g7c6R4WgEMPofRf7XqOQc=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "id-832@bot-telegram-330607.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "104225281732145252731",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/id-832%40bot- telegram-330607.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
)


sources = [{"url": "http://185.86.147.197/ozon/ways/fbs.csv", "table_name": "Исх.Ozon FBS"},
          {"url": "http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/ways/orders_fbs.csv", "table_name": "Исх.WB FBS"},
          {"url": "http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/ways/orders_fbo.csv", "table_name": "Исх.WB FBO"},
          {"url": "http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/ways/sales.csv", "table_name": "WB продажи"}]


"""http://185.86.147.197/ozon/mdl/fbs.csv на вкладку Исх.Ozon FBS
http://185.86.147.197/ozon/mdl/fbo.csv на вкладку Исх.Ozon FBO
http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/mdl/orders_fbo.csv на вкладку Исх.WB FBO
http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/mdl/orders_fbs.csv на вкладку Исх.WB FBS
http://185.86.147.197/wildberries/mdl/stocks.csv на вкладку Остатки WB FBS"""

async def start():
    wb = gc.open_by_url(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SrzQiut9- 
FKUE_3Zjf6HHia0KKr1miUthdEFKYtZoYA/edit")
    while True:
        try:
            for source in sources:
                data = pd.read_csv(source["url"], delimiter=";")
                data = data.fillna('')

                rows =[list(data)]
                for i in data.values:
                    rows.append(list(i))
                sheet = wb.worksheet(source["table_name"])
                sheet.clear()
                print(str(rows)+' - found')
                sheet.append_rows(rows)
            await asyncio.sleep(60*10)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            await asyncio.sleep(60*10)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

Выдает ошибку! Почему?
Подскажите, как правильно. Спасибо

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Администратор\Downloads\csv_sync.py", line 67
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно, просто `asyncio.run(start())` да и всё

Comment: сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

```
async def start():
    wb = gc.open_by_url(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SrzQiut9- "\
"FKUE_3Zjf6HHia0KKr1miUthdEFKYtZoYA/edit")
```